# How do I create a shortcut to another file or folder inside a folder?

Tags: internal-storage, 4.1-jelly-bean, 4.2-jelly-bean, storage, 4.3-jelly-bean

How do I create a shortcut to another file or folder inside a folder?

Example:

Suppose I go to a folder A `/storage/sdcard0/pictures`. I know that I have another folder B `/storage/sdcard1/music`. I want to create a shortcut inside folder A that point to folder B such that when I click on the shortcut, it goes to folder B.

I would appreciate if the answer is not about creating a shortcut on your home screen because this question is about creating a shortcut in a folder, not on the home screen. Thank you.

Comment: the only thing i could think of would be creating a bash file in your Directory A in which you "cd into B" .. but the Problem is If you run a bash script then it will operate only on its current environment or on those of its children, never on the parent or a completely different directory.

Comment: From a file manager? From an adb shell? Are you looking to set this up purely for navigation within the filesystem, or do you have another goal, like trying to get an app to recognize files in separate locations?

Comment: @eldarerathis, actually, I would like to set this not just only for navigation within the filesystem but also to get apps to recognize files in separate location too.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of future visitors, Android's `/sdcard` is an emulated storage, not the real filesystem. It doesn't support symlinks (what you call shortcut).

See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/203989/218526) for details.